# Cannot get PubNub React Chat tutorial to work

Tags: reactjs, webrtc, pubnub

I'm trying to run the production version of PubNub React Realtime Chat application 
(https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2016-06-14-getting-started-with-pubnub-and-react/) I wanted others user to access this application via IP address. However, when I ran the production version. It seemed like the PubNub backend service didn't work at all. I couldn't receive any message from the PubNub subscribe. Couldn't check which users are online. So, I tried to run the development version on my digital ocean server. The same thing happened. No respond from PubNub server. Could you please help me with this issue?

Below is my node-server config

```
const express = require('express');
const winston = require('winston');
const helmet = require('helmet');
const nodeProxy = require('./node-proxy');
const nodeAppServer = require('./node-app-server');
const Yelp = require("yelp");
// const http = require('http');

/**
 * Heroku-friendly production http server.
 *
 * Serves your app and allows you to proxy APIs if needed.
 */

const app = express();
// const server = http.createServer(app);

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;

// Enable various security helpers.
app.use(helmet());


// API proxy logic: if you need to talk to a remote server from your client-side
// app you can proxy it though here by editing ./proxy-config.js
nodeProxy(app);

// Serve the distributed assets and allow HTML5 mode routing. NB: must be last.
nodeAppServer(app);

// Start up the server.
app.listen(PORT, '10.18.217.126', (err) => {
  if (err) {
    winston.error(err);
    return;
  }

  winston.info(`Listening on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

Here is the PubNub subscribe:

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {setCurrentUserID, addMessage, addUser, removeUser, addMarker} from '../action';
import ChatInput from '../components/ChatInput';
import ChatHistory from '../components/ChatHistory';
import ChatUsers from '../components/ChatUsers';

const ID = Math.round(Math.random() * 1000000);
const pubnub = PUBNUB.init({
  publish_key: ‘my key',
  subscribe_key: ‘my key',
  uuid: ID,
  ssl: (location.protocol.toLowerCase() === 'https:'), // encrypt the channel
});

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  console.log(state.app.get('markers').toJS());
  return {
    history: state.app.get('messages').toJS(),
    userID: state.app.get('userID'),
    users: state.app.get('users').toJS(),
    markers: state.app.get('markers').toJS(),
    send_marker: state.app.get('send_marker'),
    // usersLocation: state.app.get('usersLocation').toJS(),
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    addMessage: (message) => dispatch(addMessage(message)),
    setUserID: (userID) => dispatch(setCurrentUserID(userID)),
    addUser: (userID) => dispatch(addUser(userID)),
    removeUser: (userID) => dispatch(removeUser(userID)),
    addMarker: (userData) => dispatch(addMarker(userData)),
    // sendMarker: (marker) => dispatch(sendMarker(marker)),
  };
}

class App extends React.Component {

  static propTypes = {
    markers: React.PropTypes.array,
    history: React.PropTypes.array,
    userID: React.PropTypes.number,
    addMessage: React.PropTypes.func,
    setUserID: React.PropTypes.func,
    users: React.PropTypes.array,
    addUser: React.PropTypes.func,
    removeUser: React.PropTypes.func,
    addMarker: React.PropTypes.func,
    sendMarker: React.PropTypes.func,
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      active: 'FIRST',
      searchBar: '',
      searchedPOI: '',
      mainNav: 'ORIGIN',
      currentLoc: '',
      goToMarker: '',
      fromWhereToMap: '',
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.fetchData();
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
      this.setState({
        currentLoc: [position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude]
      });
    });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.state.searchedPOI);
    // No geo location here you said?
    this.props.setUserID(ID);
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
      pubnub.subscribe({
        channel: 'ReactChat',
        message: this.props.addMessage,
        presence: this.onPresenceChange,
        state: {
          id: ID,
          lat: position.coords.latitude,
          lng: position.coords.longitude,
        },
      });
    });
    const self = this;
    pubnub.here_now({
      channel: 'ReactChat',
      state: true,
      uuids: true,
      callback: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        response.uuids.map((uuid) => {
          self.props.addMarker(uuid.state);
        });
      },
    });
    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', this.leaveChat);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.leaveChat();
  }

  onPresenceChange = (presenceData) => {
    switch (presenceData.action) {
      case 'join':
        // this.props.addUser([presenceData.uuid, presenceData.data.lat, presenceData.data.lng]);
        if (presenceData.data) {
          this.props.addMarker(presenceData.data);
        }
        this.props.addUser(presenceData.uuid);
        break;
      case 'leave':
        this.props.removeUser(presenceData.uuid);
        break;
      case 'timeout':
        this.props.removeUser(presenceData.uuid);
        break;
      default:
        console.error('unknown action: ' + presenceData.action);
    }
  }


  render() {
    const {props, sendMessage, state} = this;
    const active = state.active;
    const mainNav = state.mainNav;
    const searchPOI = state.searchBar;
    return (
      <div>
              <ChatUsers users={ props.users }
                     focusModal={this.onToggleNav.bind(this)}
                     currentPage={active}
                     toggleFunction={this.handleClick.bind(this)}
          />

<ChatHistory
              history={ props.history }
              getMarker={this.getMarker.bind(this)}
              me={ props.userID }
            />
<ChatInput userID={ props.userID } sendMessage={ sendMessage }/>
          </div>
)

  sendMarker(marker) {
    console.log(marker);
  }


  leaveChat = () => {
    pubnub.unsubscribe({channel: 'ReactChat'});
  };

  sendMessage = (message) => {
    pubnub.publish({
      channel: 'ReactChat',
      message: message,
    });
  };

}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(App);
```

Comment: Your code doesn't include PubNub.  Are you sure you are using PubNub?  If you are, send the code which shows your PubNub implementation.  Your original code submission is missing PubNub altogether.

Comment: @PubNub Hey I appreciate your prompt reply! here is node-server configuration from your tutorial. I just edit the pubnub code in react component. Please help! It didn't work at all on the server!

Comment: Refer to this example for node-server http://stackoverflow.com/a/42148447/524733 running your NodeJS + PubNub on a host provider.  The example shows Digital Ocean and Docker, but you can run this on any provider.

Comment: also you can always contact support@pubnub.com for faster communication.

Comment: You may also be interested in our Open Chat Framework example using ReactJS - https://github.com/pubnub/open-chat-framework/blob/master/examples/react/src/index.js

Comment: @PubNub It's still not working... I will send you more info in support@pubnub.com.  I just dont understand. It works perfectly when I rant the dev version on localhost, but when I ran the production version. Nothing works

Comment: Cool we'll connect with you on our support desk.

Comment: @PubNub Hello, so I figured it out the issue. the navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition didn't work on the production server. So, the PubNub.subscribe that I put under the geolocation function couldn't run.

Comment: i see!  Thank you for your update.